# Error de funcionamiento en botones de tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, sqlite3

Estoy haciendo una app con tkinter para un trabajo de clase. Mi intención es que genere automáticamente una serie de botones de forma automática. La cosa es que al ejecutar el código guarda todos los valores asociados a los botones como si hiciera autoclik y la verdad no tengo ni idea de por que.
Aquí esta la parte del código problemática:

```
try:
    conexion=sqlite3.connect('libreria.db')
    cursor=conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM categoria")
    cate=cursor.fetchall()
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Error: No hay datos que mostrar")
else:
    eleccion=lambda x: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pedido VALUES(null,{})".format(x))
for c in cate:
    print("\n*",c[1],"*")
    ttk.Label(marcoprincipal,text="*{}*".format(c[1])).pack(fill="both",expand=1)
    libros=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM libro WHERE categoria_id={}".format(c[0])).fetchall()
    for l in libros:
        print("\t",l[1])
        ttk.Button(marcoprincipal,text="{}".format(l[1]),command=eleccion(l[0])).pack()



conexion.commit()
conexion.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que se haga autoclick porque a `command` debes pasar una referencia a la función a llamar cuando se pulsa el botón, tu ejecutas la función y le pasas a `command` su retorno (`None`).

Por otro lado, no debes nunca usar formateo de cadenas para pasar los parámetros a una query, esto es inseguro, más cuando los parámetros provienen de entradas del usuario sin sanear. Expones tu base de datos a ataque de inyección de código. En su lugar, debes parametrizar la query.

```
from functools import partial


def eleccion(val):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pedido VALUES(null, %s)", (val, ))

for c in cate:
    print("\n*", c[1], "*")
    ttk.Label(marcoprincipal, text="*{}*".format(c[1])).pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    libros = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM libro WHERE categoria_id={%s}", (c[0], ))
    for l in libros:
        print("\t", l[1])
        ttk.Button(marcoprincipal,
                   text="{}".format(l[1]),
                   command=partial(eleccion, l[0])).pack()
```